# Can CPA secure scheme be converted to CCA secure?

Tags: encryption, public-key, provable-security, chosen-plaintext-attack, chosen-ciphertext-attack

I would like to know if there are some methods or techniques that can convert a public key encryption scheme from CPA secure to CCA secure?

Comment: See [Naor-Yung](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/gradcrypto2/NOTES/lecture7.pdf) and [Fujisaki-Okamoto](https://cs.uni-paderborn.de/fileadmin/informatik/fg/cuk/Lehre/Abschlussarbeiten/Bachelorarbeiten/2014/BA_Lippert_FOT_final.pdf) transformations.

Comment: @Occams_Trimmer  Why not offer a full answer instead of just a comment?

Answer (score 3):

There are several compilers that take a CPA-secure PKE and produce a CCA-secure PKE. I am aware of two.

The first (possibly the earliest) is the [Naor-Yung transformation](http://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Ejkatz/gradcrypto2/NOTES/lecture7.pdf) [NY], which uses a non-interactive zero-knowledge proof (NIKZ) for this purpose. Since we know how to construct NIZKs from a variety of hardness assumptions (e.g., quadratic residuosity, LWE etc.) and in the random-oracle model, we get CCA-secure PKE under these additional assumptions.

The second and arguably the more efficient/practical transformation is the [Fujisaki-Okamoto transformation](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00145-011-9114-1), which is proved secure in the random-oracle model. In fact, one can as well start with a OW-secure PKE.

[FO]: Fujisaki and Okamoto, *[Secure Integration of Asymmetric and Symmetric Encryption Schemes](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00145-011-9114-1)*, JoC'13

[NY]: Naor and Yung, *[Public-key Cryptosystems Provably Secure against Chosen Ciphertext Attacks](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/100216.100273)*, STOC'90